# Different Username at command prompt

Tags: command-prompt, administrator

I am the administrator of my laptop as rkost. But when I open the command prompt by typing cmd. I get command prompt window and it get displayed as-

```
C:\Users\owner>
```

But it should be

```
C:\Users\rkost>
```

So how can I resolve this problem. Any suggestions will be appeciated

Comment: OS? Also, off-topic - we'll move it, don't worry.

Comment: @minitech, while I agree the question is off-topic (and voted to migrate as well)... The OS in question is pretty clear: `command prompt by typing cmd`, `command prompt window`, and `C:\Users\owner>` are pretty clear indications it's Windows (Vista or newer, because of `C:\Users` instead of `C:\Documents and Settings`). :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that user-switching mechanisms change the home directory. In fact, su(8) under Solaris for example, when not requesting a login shell, does exactly that - not changing the HOME environment variable.